# Is it possible to embed JS into an <a> element to copy static text to the user's clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have a button, using an `<a>` tag, where clicking on it copies a static string of text to the user's clipboard, then changes the innerHTML to say something like 'Copied!'

Is this all possible to do within the `<a>` tag, without any extra scripts needed to be put in the code elsewhere?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code,

```js
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection;    
        
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

function copyToClipboard() {
    SelectText('copy_to_clipboard');
    document.execCommand('copy'); 
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

    document.getElementById("msg").style.display="block";
}
```

```css
#btn_select{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div><p id="copy_to_clipboard">Some text goes here!</p><p id="msg" style="display: none;">Copied!</p></div>
<a id="btn_select" onclick="copyToClipboard();">Click me!</a>
```